# Launch steam with a jQuery click on asynchronously added link

Tags: javascript, jquery, steam-web-api

I'm trying to launch the steam client using their web protocol: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Talk:Steam_browser_protocol

I'm using jQuery. Here is a example:

```
$(function() {
    // a bunch of stuff happens
    $("#content").append('<a id="launcher" href="steam://connect/' + server.ip + ':' +     server.port + '"></a>');
    $("#launcher").click();
});
```

Now I know this won't work... event delegation? But essentially it's what I want to do. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `$("#launcher")[0].click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the native DOM's `click` directly

```
$("#launcher")[0].click();
```

OR

You can use [**.get()**](http://api.jquery.com/get/), it retrieves the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object and call native DOM's `click` directly.

```
$("#launcher").get(0).click();
```

Comment: Thats a bit obscure but it makes sense. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Johandk, Whats obscure? I will try to exaplain

Comment: Is it jQuery's event delegation that causes $("#launcher").click() not to work?

Comment: @Johandk, jQuery has its own event registration system, which is separate from the DOM's event registration. When we call `$(something).click()`, all registered jQuery handlers and the registered `onclick` handler will fire, but nothing else would.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("click", "#launcher", function () {
    // code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.trigger()`:

```
$("#launcher").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Already tried that. Because the link is added on the fly it doesn't work.